# Displaying all woocommerce product liks with title in Footer for SEO - Wordpress PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce

I am wanting to display all woocommerce products with links with the woocommerce title on the links top help my SEO. I have managed to find some code below which gets the product categories but cant seem to get the code to display all products with the title on the links.

If anyone knows any code that could help me I would be very grateful to get all products with links and title! p.s if there is a better way to fetch the data than I have used, please let me know!

```
<?php
                  $taxonomy     = 'product_cat';
                  $orderby      = 'name';  
                  $show_count   = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
                  $pad_counts   = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
                  $hierarchical = 1;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no  
                  $title        = '';  
                  $empty        = 0;
                $args = array(
                  'taxonomy'     => $taxonomy,
                  'orderby'      => $orderby,
                  'show_count'   => $show_count,
                  'pad_counts'   => $pad_counts,
                  'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
                  'title_li'     => $title,
                  'hide_empty'   => $empty
                );
                ?>
                                
                <?php $all_categories = get_categories( $args );
                //print_r($all_categories);
                foreach ($all_categories as $cat) {
                    //print_r($cat);
                    if($cat->category_parent == 0) {
                        $category_id = $cat->term_id;
                ?>  
                                    
                <?php       
                
                        echo '<a href="'. get_term_link($cat->slug, 'product_cat') .'">' . $cat->name .'</a>'; ?> |
                
                    <?php }     
                }
                ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you wants ?

```
//you can remove post_status=>publish if you want unpublished product also
$loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'product','post_status' => 'publish', 'posts_per_page' => '-1' ) ); 

while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    echo "<a href='".get_post_permalink()."'>".$loop->post->post_title."</a><br>";
endwhile;
```

**EDITED**

change query like this :

```
$loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'product','post_status' => 'publish', 'posts_per_page' => '-1', 'orderby' => 'title', 'order' => 'ASC' ) );
```

Comment: This is perfect! thank you very much! I am now trying to arrange it by name if you know anything to do this?